# How to adjust two divs in views.py

Tags: python, html, django

I have made a loop in `divs`. First div is for first column and another div for second column. I just want it to manage in `views.py`. I made two functions in `views.py` for two separate `divs`.  But it is not showing me the result of last function. It is just showing me the first function pics and only the first div is working.

```
index.html  
{% static 'images/fulls' as baseUrl %}
{% static 'images/thumbs' as hiUrl %}
   <div class="row">
{% for dest in dest1 %}
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}}">
      <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="" />
      <h3>{{destt.desc}}</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
{%endfor%}
</div>
{% for destt in dest2 %}                                
   <div>
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{destt.img}}">
    <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{destt.img}}" alt="" />
    <h3>{{destt.desc}}</h3>
      </a>
   </div>
    {% endfor %}

views.py
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.desc = 'Hello, How arE you?'
    dest1.img = '01.jpg'
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dest1':dest1})

def nextt(request):
    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.desc = 'Hello, How arE you?'
    dest2.img = '02.jpg'
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dest2':dest2})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def index(request):
    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.desc = 'Hello, How arE you?'
    dest1.img = '01.jpg'

    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.desc = 'Hello, How arE you?'
    dest2.img = '02.jpg'

    context = {
        "dest1": dest1,
        "dest2": dest2
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two different views. The `index` function can be used as a view, the `nextt` function too. To see the second five with your current setup, you will have to add a route pointing to the `nextt` if you don't have one already (I guess you don't) function from which you will be able to see it.

Django routes points to functions or classes not modules.

Another possible solution is to merge both the `index` and `nextt` into a function and use a condition to decide which view to show.